# force:refreshView : Lightning component for Flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

So, I have a fairly simple flow, see below:

[image: Flow]

My problem is the Core Action, I've found and tried so many variations for force:refreshView, but I can't get it to work. Can anyone show me a sample .cmp and sample .js so that I can get the record to refresh after two fields are updated from the Flow.

Comment: I don't think Flow will work like that.  You should try getting the record you updated before reaching the screen.